What are the mechanisms behind the shift of C-C bonds in XPS and FTIR spectra of graphene oxides due to cation−π interactions?
The literature describes the occurrence of cation-π interactions between metals and the plane of graphene oxide, through its benzene rings, which function as π-electron donors. As evidence of this mechanism, authors use the shift of the C=C peaks in the FTIR [1] and XPS spectra, for example. I would like to know please what are the mechanisms in cation–π interactions that ultimately lead to the shift of the C-C peaks in the spectra.
[1] Aggregation, Adsorption, and Morphological Transformation of
Graphene Oxide in Aqueous Solutions Containing Different Metal Cations
Thank you
